# Help need with formatting returned SQL data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've created a table which approximates to this:

```
Fruit  |  Date Purchased  |  Amount Purchased
----------------------------------------------
Apples  |  01-01-10  |  5
Oranges |  01-01-10  |  7
Apples  |  02-01-10  |  3
Oranges |  02-01-10  |  2
etc....
```

I need to end up with the data in the following format though:

```
Apples (
    (01-01-10, 5),
    (02-01-10, 3)
)

Oranges (
    (01-01-10, 7),
    (02-01-10, 2)
)
etc...
```

The types of fruit are not fixed - more will be added over time, so this would be need to be taken into account.

I've been stuck on this for quite a while now, so any pointers or tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you provide some details? What Db are you using? and I am assuming you require your 'code' output to be like that? (because sql does not produce resulsets like that)

Comment: Hi M.R. It's a MySQL DB. I'm guessing that I'll have to push the data into a PHP multi-dimensional array to achieve the format I require, but I'm not sure my table structure is ideal either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all all your records and add every row to the appropriate array:

Something like:

```
$fruits = array();

while ($row = get_new_database_row)       /* depends on mysql, mysqli, PDO */
{
  $fruits[$row['fruit']][] = array($row['date'], $row['amount']);
}
```

**Edit:** Based on your codeigniter comments, you either need [`result_array()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) or you need to change `$row['fruit']` to `$row->fruit`, `$row['date']` to `$row->date`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying jeroen. Unfortunately I'm recieiving an error with this. When using the CodeIgnitor "foreach" to loop through the results, I get the error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ...". When using the PHP "mysql_fetch_array", I get the error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given". It's getting late now, so I'll try and work out what this problem is tomorrow. Thanks anyway.

Comment: why don't you tell us earlier, if you use CodeIgniter?

Comment: Because the question was regarding MySQL/PHP and not specific to CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2):

I to lazy to figure out the correct HTML tag to do the tab, but the following code should help you out.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  s.Fruit, ' (<br/>', '<tab/>',
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.DatePlusAmount SEPARATOR ',<br/><tab>'),
  '<br/>)<br/>') as FruitLine FROM 
  (
    SELECT Fruit, CONCAT(PDate, ',', IFNULL(sum(amount),0)) AS DatePlusAmount 
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY DATE
  ) s
  GROUP BY Fruit
```

No loops in php needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabledata";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while( false !== ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)))
{
   $arr_fruit[ $r['fruit'] ][ $r['date_purchase'] ] = $r['amout'];
}
```

at this point, you'll end up having associative array that you can further process.

I leave that as an exercise. Come back again when you have problem. But, be sure to bring some code.

Comment: I don´t think there´s a need for another query in a loop, you can get all rows at once. Also, depending on the OP's requirements (multiple purchases on the same day) it might not be a good idea to use the date as an array key.

Comment: Thanks silent, I'll take a closer look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @jeroen, yup, you are right, it should be only one query. I'll fix it.